# Is it possible to block Android market programatically?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to enable/disable the Android market programmatically for my kids app (with a checkbox). Is this possible? How?

Comment: Do you want to remove it all-together? Or just set a passcode for purchases? Do you need to create a {Program} to do this, or do you mean you just want the OS to disable it?

Comment: I want to show a dialog with message if the checkbox is checked and user tried to launch android market.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the play store, do as you would with any other app if you were going to delete it, however in replace of the delete buttin wil be a disable button.

If you do not want to disable it all together, you can open the app, click menu, and then settings, and then half way down on the list you are abe to set a passcode for purchases.

**EDIT**
I know hat you said programmatically, however this could still be a solution as to what you may be looking for instead as a workaround.

Comment: He said 'programmatically' :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, no. You cannot affect the behaviour of other apps from your app. There are tricks that allow you to monitor what has been stated and you can bring your own app in the foreground to sort of 'block' it, but this is neither supported, nor guaranteed to work on all devices and Android versions.

Comment: Is it possible to block launching of apps using package name?

Comment: This is achieved in KidsPlace apps.Do you have any idea?

Comment: As I said, they are doing different tricks to achieve it, it is not directly supported. For the exact method, ask the dev or reverse the app. In any case it is not likely to work reliably.